# jqbanner.js - Jquery Banner Not Functional in Firefox

Tags: jquery, transition, banner

**[SOLUTION DISCOVERED. SEE BELOW]**

I'm trying to get a jquery banner working in Firefox, but am presently stuck - It's working in IE8 and Chrome but not in Firefox for some strange reason?

[Here's the homepage where the banner is located](http://warehouseinabox.com)

And [this is the banner it's using](http://www.mclelun.com/blog/2010/01/jquery-rotating-banner/)

Below you can see the chunk of js that should be creating the fade effect upon transition or click-through. Let me know if you would like to analyze any other piece of code that relates to this page in order to find a resolution.

I've read a couple things online in terms of jquery and opacity transition issues but haven't had any luck - Maybe you guys could pass a tip?

***PS - The banner is present on the page, but looks like it may be conflicting with something to corrupt the transitions.**

```
var jqb_eff = 1;

//Variables
var jqb_vCurrent = 0;
var jqb_vTotal = 0;
var jqb_vSpeed = 800;
var jqb_vDuration = 6000;
var jqb_intInterval = 0;
var jqb_vGo = 1;
var jqb_vBusy = false;
var jqb_vIsPause = true;
var jqb_tmp = 20;
var jqb_title;
var jqb_imgW = 1150;
var jqb_imgH = 445;

jQuery(document).ready(function() { 
jqb_vTotal = $(".jqb_slides").children().size() -1;
$(".jqb_info").text($(".jqb_slide").attr("title")); 
jqb_intInterval = setInterval(jqb_fnLoop, jqb_vDuration);

if(jqb_eff == 1)//Fade In & Fade Out
{
    $("#jqb_object").find(".jqb_slide").each(function(i) { 
        if(i == 0){
            $(this).animate({ opacity: 'show'}, jqb_vSpeed, function() { jqb_vBusy = false; });
        } else {
            $(this).animate({ opacity: 'hide'}, jqb_vSpeed, function() { jqb_vBusy = false; });
        }
    });
}
```

**[SOLUTION]**

*Disregard assistance engagement, I have found the solution and would like to share it in order to maintain a log for others in case of encountering the same issue.*

- Discovered the issue - Since I was using Joomla CMS, there is a
  plugin which enables **mootools** alongside. After deactivating this
  plugin, the jquery banner works 100% properly - most likely a conflict in the script that firefox dislikes.

Comment: Put your solution in the answer field below or close your question, please.

Answer (score 0):

Discovered the issue - Since I was using Joomla CMS, there is a plugin which enables mootools alongside. After deactivating this plugin, the jquery banner works 100% properly - most likely a conflict in the script that firefox dislikes.